# Changing permissions for every file matching a pattern

Tags: unix

How do you change the access permission (add group read/write) to all the files in the current directory containing the word "test"

Answer (score 7):

You could use:

```
chmod g+rw *test* .*test*
```

Or:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*test*' -exec chmod g+rw {} +
```